# I am using button in Lightning table and i wish to remove the button border. I try to give css class in typeAtributes but it doesn't work. Any help?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

Column definition

```js
{
    label: 'Name',
    fieldName: 'Name',
    type: 'button',
    initialWidth: 200,
    typeAttributes:
    {
        label: { fieldName: 'Name'},
        class: "borderRemove"
    },
    sortable: true
}
```

//css class

```css
.borderRemove {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [datatable documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) you can see that for type `button` there is `variant` in supported type attributes.
Then in [lightning-button documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button/documentation) you can read about `variant` (emphasis mine):

> `base` is a **button without a border**, which gives it the look of a plain text link.

So, other than using Styling Hooks, you could set `variant: 'base'` in typeAttributes:

```js
{
    label: 'Name',
    fieldName: 'Name',
    type: 'button',
    initialWidth: 200,
    typeAttributes:
    {
        label: { fieldName: 'Name'},
        variant: 'base'
    },
    sortable: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Styling Hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/) you can apply custom style to the Button.

*CSS*

```
.customBorder {
    --slds-c-button-sizing-border : 0;
}
```

*HTML*

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <lightning-datatable class = "customBorder" key-field="employeeId" data={employeeData} columns={employeeColumns}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

*JS*

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class DataTableExample extends LightningElement {
    employeeColumns = [
        {
            label: 'Action', type: 'button', typeAttributes:
                { label: 'View Record', name: 'viewRecord', disabled: false, value: 'viewBtn' }
        },
        { label: 'Employee Id', fieldName: 'employeeId' },
        { label: 'First Name', fieldName: 'firstName' },
        { label: 'Last Name', fieldName: 'lastName' },
        { label: 'Phone Number', fieldName: 'employeePhone', type: 'phone' },
        { label: 'Email Address', fieldName: 'employeeEmail', type: 'email' }
    ];

    employeeData = [
        {
            employeeId: '1',
            firstName: 'Richard',
            lastName: 'Hendricks',
            employeePhone: '(158) 389-2794',
            employeeEmail: 'richard@piedpiper.com'
        },
        {
            employeeId: '2',
            firstName: 'Jared',
            lastName: 'Dunn',
            employeePhone: '(518) 390-2749',
            employeeEmail: 'jared@piedpiper.com'
        },
        {
            employeeId: '3',
            firstName: 'Erlich',
            lastName: 'Bachman',
            employeePhone: '(815) 391-2974',
            employeeEmail: 'erlich.bachman@piedpiper.com'
        }
    ];
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is not working